# Blender 2.8 - Moving Light Inside of an Object

Tags: animation, light

I have a light inside of a wire (simple bezier curve) in Blender 2.8 and I'm wondering how I can get it to animate and move inside of the wire curve?  I'd like it to follow all the curves and loops of the wire itself.

[image: Current wire animation is just a single frame for now]

I'm looking for a faster way than hand-animating it with individual keyframes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many very similar questions about objects following paths answered on Blender's StackExchange. Is there a particular challenge that you've encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Assuming you "wire" is an actual Bezier curve object, just animate the light along the curve with a curve constraint.

Parent the light object to curve with *Path Constraint* by selecting first the lamp object, then the curve and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> *Set Parent to > Path Constraint*.

[image]

Under the constraints tab click the *Animate Path* if necessary, and adjust the pace from the curve *Object data > Path Animation > Frames*

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I was missing, it's working perfectly now

Comment: Is it possible to show only the animated light and not the mesh / curve where it runs along?